# How do I indent code in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I easily indent all my code by four spaces using Notepad++? I am trying to post on SO inside code blocks, but I don't want to manually add spaces for a bunch of lines of code.

Comment: If it matters, in SO you can highlight it all and then use `ctrl-k` to auto indent it all

Comment: That's awesome, will you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add spaces in front of every line in Notepad++ do this:

1) Open the replace menu (in find, click the replace tab)

2) Enter this in the 'Find what' box

```
([^\n]+)
```

3)Enter this in the 'Replace with' box (four spaces followed by a \1)

```
    \1
```

4) select the radio button for 'Regular expression' in the 'Search Mode' field

5) Hit 'Replace All'

Answer (score 0):

Select all the lines you want to indent, then press on <kbd>Tabulation</kbd>

Comment: That will indent by one tab, not 4 spaces

Comment: @Rilcon42: It depends on how you've configured. Npp. Go to `Settings > preferences > Tabulations` then check `insert spaces`. After that spaces will be inserted when you press on `Tab`.

Comment: Will you add your comment to your answer so everyone will see it?

Answer (score 0):

Select all the lines you want to indent, then press on "tabulation", if you want to un-indent select the lines and press shift+tab.

Comment: That will indent by one tab, not 4 spaces